# Блокировка всех запросов, кроме некоторых сайтов

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

**Основная задача** - заблокировать все соединения, в том числе исходящие, кроме заданных IP и пары сайтов ( ru.archive.ubuntu.com, api.vk.com, discord.com ).

С первой частью я справляюсь, однако предоставить доступ к конкретным сайтам не получается уже который день, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

**Пробовал**:

1. Разрешать доступ по конкретному IP сайта ( `iptables -A OUTPUT -d IP -j ACCEPT` ).
2. Разрешать доступ по "route" из `host -t a Сайт` -> `whois IP`.
3. Пытаться разрешить доступ по домену ( `iptables -A OUTPUT -d DOMEN -j ACCEPT`, iptables не дал ).

Используемые команды:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -s xx.xx.xx.xx -d "$SERVERIP" -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s "$SERVERIP" -d xx.xx.xx.xx -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Если упростить задачу до "блокировать все http, кроме нескольких сайтов", то можно использовать специализированный инструмент - [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/http_access/)

Comment: @Total Pusher, в моём случае необходима конкретно блокировка всех исходящих, чтобы через какую-нибудь дыру ( аля Log4jExploit ) нельзя было загрузить файл и выкачать данные в обход SSH/FTP.

Comment: Лучше использовать корпоративное решение. Решение IP tables - наколеночное, и для бедных. PS. И склонное к превращению в лапшу по мере добавления правил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Современные большие сайты это не один IP адрес, а целые экосистемы.

Например чтоб открыть VK нужно открыть несколько подсетей

```
87.240.128.0/18
93.186.224.0/20
95.142.192.0/20
95.213.0.0/17
185.32.248.0/22
```

К решению задачи можно подойти так:

Во-первых исправить правила - разрешить входящие. Запрета исходящих достаточно для блокировки. Или использовать контрак (для ненагруженных систем) `iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

Во-вторых разрешить адреса DNS серверов.

Далее открыть tcpdump, wireshark, инспектор браузера или `netstat -ntp | grep пид_процесса` на котором тестишь и смотреть куда уходят не отвеченные запросы.

Анализируй к чему относятся эти адреса, в случае wireshark и инспектора браузера увидишь домен.

Этот домен пробей через dig, чтоб получить альтернативные адреса серверов.

Пробей эти адреса через whois, чтоб посмотреть чей это хостинг и в случае если весь диапазон принадлежит сайту - открыть весь диапазон.

Чтоб браузер не "зависал" используй tcp reset вместо дропа.

Адреса лучше забивать в ipset.

Comment: Касаемо первого пункта, точно заблокируются все возможные ситуации? Была идея с каким-нибудь JNDI-эксплойтом, но там вроде тоже OUT пакеты будут... Как минимум, в компании работает множество людей, теоретически, на тестовом сервере недобросовестный разработчик может узнать про какое-нибудь API и проколупать его запросами уже на продакшене, чего быть не должно.

Comment: Про получения множества IP посмотрел в вашем другом ответе, благодарю) Такой ещё вопросик, если сайт назначения стоит на CloudFlare, спасёт данная команда или только для одного шлюза разблокирует, который потом может поменяться?

Comment: возможно стоит запретить все и работать через прокси в таком случае